# Convolution product calculation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

We consider the convolution product:

\begin{align*}
 \varphi(\xi)=(1+|\xi|^2)^{2/3}*\frac{e^{-|\xi|^2}}{\pi^{d/2}}
 \end{align*}

for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d$  such that $|\xi|\ge1$.

I want to prove that there existe a constant $c>0$ such that

$| \varphi(\xi)|\le (1+|\xi|^2)^{2/3}$

for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d$  such that $|\xi|\ge1$.

Thanks

Comment: I tried whit an other function which is $f(\xi)=|\xi|^{4/3}*\frac{e^{-|\xi|^2}}{\pi^{d/2}}$ and i proved the result but i dn't know how to do with $ \varphi(\xi)$. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In explicit terms,
$$ \frac{\varphi(\xi)}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{2/3}} = \frac{1}{\pi^{d/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left(\frac{1+|\xi-z|^2}{1+|\xi|^2}\right)^{2/3} e^{-|z|^2}\,d\mu $$
and in order to prove that the RHS is bounded by an absolute constant is it enough to split $\mathbb{R}^d$ as $\{|z|\leq |\xi|\}\cup\{|z|>|\xi|\}$. Since $|\xi|\geq 1$,
$$ \int_{|z|\leq |\xi|}\left(\frac{1+|\xi-z|^2}{1+|\xi|^2}\right)^{2/3} e^{-|z|^2}\,d\mu\leq 4^{2/3}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-|z|^2}\,dz =C_0$$
and similarly
$$ \int_{|z|> |\xi|}\left(\frac{1+|\xi-z|^2}{1+|\xi|^2}\right)^{2/3} e^{-|z|^2}\,d\mu\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(3|z|^2)^{2/3}e^{-|z|^2}\,dz =C_1$$
so
$$ \frac{\left|\varphi(\xi)\right|}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{2/3}}\leq C_0+C_1.$$
Sharper bounds can be derived from [Young's convolution inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality).

Comment: i didn't understand how you find the  $3|z|^2$ in the second inequality, can you please explain more? thanks

Comment: @siwi: if $|z|>|\xi|$, $\frac{1+|\xi-z|^2}{1+|\xi|^2}\leq \frac{1+2|\xi|^2+2|z|^2}{2}<3|z|^2$.